# What are the elements in $\Gamma(\Lambda^2 TM)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, symplectic-geometry, poisson-geometry

In the [lecture notes](http://toknotes.mimuw.edu.pl/sem4/files/Ciccoli_fpqg.pdf), Proposition 1.19 on page 9, it is said that on every Poisson manifold there is a unique bivector ﬁeld $\Pi \in \Gamma(\Lambda^2 TM)$ such that $$ \{f, g\} = \langle  \Pi, df \wedge dg \rangle. $$

I think that $f, g \in C^{\infty}(M, \mathbb{R})$ and $df, dg \in T^*M$. Therefore $df \wedge dg \in \Lambda^2 T^*M$. Why here $\Pi \in \Gamma(\Lambda^2 TM)$ but not in $\Gamma(\Lambda^2 T^*M)$? What are the form of elements in $\Gamma(\Lambda^2 TM)$ Thank you very much.

Edit: is the following true? $\Pi^*: \Lambda^2(T_x^*M) \to C^{\infty}(M)$, $\langle \Pi, df \wedge dg \rangle = \Pi^*(df \wedge dg) \in C^{\infty}(M)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author is using $\langle,\rangle$ to denote the natural pairing between $\Lambda^2TM$ and its dual $\Lambda^2 T^*M$.

Comment: thank you very much. But usually the value of a pairing $\langle, \rangle$ is in the ground field ( in this case, $\mathbb{R}$ ). But here it seems that we should have the value of $\langle, \rangle$ is in $C^{\infty}(M)$.

Comment: @LJR: Indeed the result is in $C^\infty(M)$ - the pairing is fibre-wise: $\langle \alpha, \beta \rangle (x) = \langle \alpha(x), \beta(x) \rangle$. This is because the duality is with respect to the module $C^\infty(M)$, not the field $\mathbb R$.

Comment: ^ mistake: module should be ring.

Comment: if $\beta \in \Gamma(\Lambda^2 T^*M)$, is $\beta$ a map from $M$ to $\Lambda^2 T^*M$? Thank you very much.

Comment: thank you very much. I am still confused. I think that $\Pi \in \Gamma(\Lambda^2 TM)$ (not in $\Lambda^2 TM$) and $df \wedge dg \in \Lambda^2 T^*M$ (not in $\Gamma(\Lambda^2 T^*M)$). Why the pairing is between $\Lambda^2 TM$ and $\Lambda^2 T^*M$?

Comment: @LJR: $df$ and $dg$ are sections of $T^* M$, so their wedge is a section of $\Lambda^2 T^* M$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to be a bit more general and deal with general multivectors. We have an isomorphism of $C^\infty(M)$-modules: $$\Gamma(\Lambda^k TM)\longrightarrow \textrm{Alt}^k_{C^\infty(M)}(\Omega^1(M), C^\infty(M)),$$ where $\Omega^1(M):=\Gamma(T^*M)$. The isomorphism is done as follows:

$$\Pi\longmapsto ((\omega_1, \ldots, \omega_k)\longmapsto \langle \Pi, \omega_1\wedge\ldots \wedge \omega_k\rangle),$$
where $\langle \Pi, \omega_1\wedge \ldots \wedge \omega_k\rangle$ is the smooth function on $M$ defined by:

$$\langle \Pi, \omega_1\wedge \ldots \wedge \omega_k\rangle(p):=(\omega_1\wedge \ldots \wedge \omega_k)_p(\Pi_p).$$ To understand the above definition notice:

(i) $\Pi_p\in \Lambda^k T_pM$

(ii) $(\omega_1\wedge \ldots \omega_k)_p:=(\omega_1)_p\wedge \ldots (\omega_k)_p\in \Lambda^k T_p^*M\simeq \textrm{Hom}_{\mathbb R}(\Lambda^k T_pM, \mathbb R)$ so that it makes sense $(\omega_1\wedge \ldots \wedge \omega_k)_p(\Pi_p)$.

As to the form of $\Pi$ we must work locally: Take $(U, x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ a local coordinate system of $M$ around $p$. Then $\{(\partial_{x_1})_p, \ldots, (\partial_{x_n})_p\}$ is a basis of $T_pM$ hence:

$$\{(\partial_{x_{j_1}})_p\wedge \ldots \wedge (\partial_{x_{j_k}})_p: j_1<\ldots<j_k\}$$ is a basis of $\Lambda^k T_pM$, hence:

$$\Pi_p=\sum_{j_1<\ldots<j_k} f_{j_1\ldots j_k}(p) (\partial_{x_{j_1}})_p\wedge \ldots (\partial_{x_{j_k}})_p,$$ for suitable scalars $f_{j_1\ldots j_k}(p)$. Hence, on $U$:$$\Pi=\sum_{j_1<\ldots <j_k} f_{j_1\ldots j_k} \partial_{x_{j_1}}\wedge \ldots \wedge \partial_{x_{j_k}}$$ where $f_{j_1\cdots j_k}\in C^\infty(U)$.